# Compilation Error after inputing in several main files

Tags: texstudio

I am writing two seperate documents, where I can use parts of the main text for both. Currently I am having two main.tex files, where I \input{content} the respective parts, such that if i change content.tex, the changes are available in both main bodies. After it worked at the beginning, the compiler now gives me an error when trying to compile the whole document from the content.tex, saying that "\begin{document} is missing". Is is possible that LaTeX can't handle the fact that I giving it two options to use as main.tex? Is there any workaround to still achieve the wished behaviour?

Edit: I'm working in TeXstudio 2.10.8 with texlive on an Kubuntu 16.04 machine

---

Clearification:

File structure:

main1.tex

-- content.tex

main2.tex

-- content.tex

Where the -- denotes the \input{content.tex} command. In both main files I am having the respective \include{} commands. After setting this up, I was able to hit F5 in Texstudio with the content.tex file open, which recompiled main1.tex.

---

Solution:

As indicated by Mirco this is a TeXstudio related problem. I was able to solve it using "Options/Root Document/Set Current Document As Explicit Root" in the menubar when having the wished main-file open.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) sadly I left my magic crystal ball at home, so you'll need to provide us with a lot more information. Like what kind of ever do you get. What is the structure of your documents., What exactly are you compiling, do you remember compiling the main doc (the one that has the preamble) instead of the included doc?

Comment: @daleif it is organised as follows:
..include statements..
\begin{document}

\input{content}

\end{document}. Earlier, when working with such constructs i was able to directly compile the document from the content.tex file, provided the main was open. This does not work, giving me the above described "\begin{document} is missing" error

Comment: I'm afraid that in its current form, your query isn't very clear. In particular, the hierarchy of dependencies between `content.tex`, `main1.tex`, and `main2.tex` could be improved. That would also help in understanding the sentence "trying to compile the whole document from the content.tex" -- which "whole document" are you referring to?

Comment: @Mico I added further information, is it now clearer?

Comment: Not all that much, I'm afraid. :-(  I've taken the liberty of changing the query's tag from "input" to "texstudio", as it appears to be mainly about TeXstudio-related functionality.

Comment: @Mico Great, that hint already solved the problem. Indeed one is able to set the Options->Root document in Texstudio manually, as the automatic detection seems to fail in this case.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments.